# Responsive images side by side with same height different width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

my issue is in image: [image]

example of desktop resolution: [image]

In server i want to use default size pictures (800x450px). So i need to resize and crop images with css to fit container `div's width` and keep same height of all images in row. Then on window resize images has to keep aspect ratio.

Html code example:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container col-7">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450/sports/1/" alt="">
    <h2>Title1</h2>
</div>
<div class="container col-5">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450/sports/2/" alt="">
    <h2>Title2</h2>
</div>
<div class="container col-5">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450/sports/3/" alt="">
    <h2>Title3</h2>
</div>
<div class="container col-4">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450/sports/4/" alt="">
    <h2>Title4</h2>
</div>
<div class="container col-3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450/sports/5/" alt="">
    <h2>Title5</h2>
</div>
```

css example:

```
.wrap { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container img { 
    width: 100%; 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: no. But if i need, then there is no problem to use it

Comment: Ok, well where's the CSS for the `col-` classes? I wasn't sure if you were misusing the bootstrap classes.

Comment: .col-12 { width: 100%; } .col-7 { width: 58.333333333%;} .col-5 { width: 41.666666667%;} .col-4 { width: 33.333333333%;} .col-3 { width: 25%;}

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be, if possible, to show the images as div backgrounds. Then you could use css3 background-properties such as

CSS:

```
div {
      background-image:url('image-url-here');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size:cover;
      background-position: center; 
  }
```

So for example your image divs could be something like

HTML:

```
<div class="container col-7">
    <div id="id1" class="myImage"></div>
    <h2>Title1</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .myImage {
              background-repeat:no-repeat;
              background-size:cover;
              background-position: center; 
              width: 100%;
              height: 450px;
            }

   #id1     {
              background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/800/450/sports/1/');
            }
```

Comment: image height also has to be responsive and keep aspect ratio of original photo.

Comment: You can set the .myImage height to be responsive. The background-size property keeps the image aspect ratio intact.

Comment: and how to do that ?

Comment: You could use vh values, for example height: 60vh; , which equals 60/100 of browser window height. It would be easier to use Bootstrap and fixed height values, but vh should work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! a have used vw values. Not the vh